# ParticleInstance modifier doesn’t list any particle systems

Tags: particles, hair

I’m trying to create some low poly fur. I’ve created a plane with an image of my fur texture on it. I want to use a ParticleInstance modifier to create the hair geometry since this will allow me to bend my hair geometry along the hair shaft (and the default particle system modifier does not). However, when I add the ParticleInstance modifier, the drop down box where you need to select the particle system is empty even though my model does have a particle system on it. How do I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I needed to add the ParticleInstance modifier to the hair model, not the monkey model.